# Updating a Table in Access Using VBA and SQL for a Forecasting Process

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

So my question deals with a series of forms and buttons that prompts the user to put in information for a forecasting process. When they click on the update button, it stores it into a table. However, what I need to be able to do is take what is in that table, search for the most recent record, and then append that data to another table. Sounds simple enough, but it gets a little more complicated, to me at least.

So the way the records are stored are by a date and month value which looks like this YYMM (so if it was September 2019 it would look like 1809). I want to be able to make a button that the user can press on a monthly basis checking to see the most recent records and posting that for the rest of the year.

This is hard to explain over text, but I will do my best. The user presses the button to update the second table and its looking at each record and updating every instance after the most recent occurrence.

Here's what it would look like visually with goofy names for the columns:

Table 1, the one the user is updating at random

```
DATE  Animal_ID  Species  Breed  Treats
1807  000342     Dog       Lab   5
1806  002342     Cat       Tabby 20
```

So obviously there would be more records, but it would look random like that.

Here's table 2, the one that is keeping track of forecasting.

```
DATE  Animal_ID  Species  Breed  Treats
1801  000342     Dog       Lab   3
1802  000342     Dog       Lab   3
1803  000342     Dog       Lab   3
1804  000342     Dog       Lab   3
1805  000342     Dog       Lab   3
1806  000342     Dog       Lab   3
1807  000342     Dog       Lab   3
1808  000342     Dog       Lab   3
1809  000342     Dog       Lab   3
1810  000342     Dog       Lab   3
1811  000342     Dog       Lab   3
1812  000342     Dog       Lab   3
1801  002342     Cat       Tabby 2
1802  002342     Cat       Tabby 2
....
```

I'm not sure if that makes sense, but the second table already will exist with prepopulated data. So if the user pressed the append button, it should then replace everything 1807 and after for the dog with that data, and everything 1806 and after for the cat.

Like I said, not the easiest to explain, but I hope I got some of what I'm trying to do across. I'd be more than happy to elaborate more if necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create one query where you get a list of the Animal_ID and the highest date.
Create another query containing the forecast table and the query above, joining on the animal_id and date.